# Rails polymorphic association call model that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I've a problem with call model that doesn't exist. I have model `CommandSet` that is on polymorphic association with model `RecordLevelSecurity` that has `securable` field that can contains `IbmiCommandSet` or `CommandSet`. I've a just one model for `IbmiCommandSet` and `CommandSet` and it's of course `CommandSet`.So than I have tried  find `Role` with `RecordLevelPermission`that is contains `RecordLevelSecurity`'s id.Rails gives following error after my attempt Find Role.

```
 def edit
   @system_settings = @@system_settings
   @role = Role.find(params[:id], :include => {:record_level_permissions =>    {:record_level_security => :securable}})
   set_view_only
   if !params[:page] && !params[:list]
    show_role
    elsif params[:list]
    render_list_partial
   else
    render_edit_partial
   end
 end

NameError (uninitialized constant IbmiCommandSet):
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2105:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1170:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1170:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:56:in `edit'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
```